# How to show more digits in blender when working at a small scale

Tags: units, measurement

How can I get more digits in the user interface for modeling.

Of course we can scale up the scene always, but that is just annoying, I like to work in millimeters for example which is possible with the Metric settings in blender, but the UI only shows floating point up to 3 digits?

Is there any way of improving this? Especially the scale in the transform property tab only shows 3 digits, that's annoying :-)

Comment: when you define the properties, you set the  precision for the display so i think this will be hard to achieve

Answer (score 12):

In the Units section, select not only metric, but change the scale to .001 to work in milimiters instead of meters.

[image]

You should be able to work numerically in a very small scale then.

[image]

Doing operations using keyboard shortcuts works now at the scale you've set, meaning that if you want to move something 2mm in the X axis, for example, you'd press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

To make navigating and manipulation easier, remember to set the scale of the 3D viewport as well.

[image]

Comment: How to do that but for internal values (like the camera shift) ? (I have driver, clicking it only show me driver and not the current value)

Answer (score 4):

For 2.8+ you simply need to change the Units to Millimeter (leave the scale at 1). I find that updating the unit scale plays havoc with other objects, like camera and lighting.

[image]

Optionally update the Viewport Overlay Floor scale to .001 (as to achieve incremental grid lines that apply to a smaller scale object)

[image]