# Show decimal point digits on Dimensions tool

Tags: dimensions

I'm trying to work with precise values in Blender and I found this weird thing where the Dimensions tool only shows the full decimal point value when selected.

Now I know I could change the unit scale on the scene properties, but what if I want to work in meters, but in a given object I want to be able to check dimensions more precisely (in millimeters for instance)

[image]
[image]

Why does it happen? Is there an option to change this?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How to show more digits in blender when working at a small scale](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31452/how-to-show-more-digits-in-blender-when-working-at-a-small-scale)